# dynamically added panel becomes visible only on resizing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

```
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;

public class Welcome extends FrameView 
{
    SearchPanelClass panel1 = new SearchPanelClass();
    AddMaterialPanel panel2 = new AddMaterialPanel();
    Container container= AutomobileApplication.getApplication().getMainFrame();
    public Welcome(SingleFrameApplication app) 
    {
       super(app);
       initMenu();
}

private class MenuAction implements ActionListener {

private SearchPanelClass panel;
private MenuAction(SearchPanelClass pnl) 
{

    this.panel = pnl;

}
private AddMaterialPanel AddMaterialPan;
private MenuAction(AddMaterialPanel pnl) 
{
    this.AddMaterialPan = pnl;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command == "Panel1")
    {
        changePanel(panel1);
    }
    if(command =="Panel2")
    {
        changePanel(panel2);
    }

   }

 }

private void initMenu() {

JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("Panel1");
JMenuItem menuItem2 = new JMenuItem("Panel2");
menubar.add(menu);
menu.add(menuItem1);
menu.add(menuItem2);
this.setMenuBar(menubar);
menuItem1.addActionListener(new MenuAction(panel1));
menuItem2.addActionListener(new MenuAction(panel2));

}

private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
container.removeAll();
setComponent(panel);
panel.setVisible(true);
container.doLayout(); 
  }
}
```

Here SearchPanelClass and AddMaterialPanel are two custom panels which I want to add according to the menuitem click. But panels become visible only on resizing window. Can any one tell me which procedures are called in back end on window resizing?

Please helm me...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you add the main(String[] args) please?

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra its just practice but then also thnks for advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container that is having JPanels added to it or removed from it.

- `revalidate()` will tell the container to have its layout manager re-lay out all of the components that it holds.
- `repaint()` will tell the component to redraw itself and all of its children. This is not always needed but is often needed, especially if components are removed.

Also, never use `==` to compare Strings as you do here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();
    if(command == "Panel1")
    {
        changePanel(panel1);
    }
    if(command =="Panel2")
    {
        changePanel(panel2);
    }

   }

 }
```

The `==` operator will check if two String objects are one and the same, something you don't care about. Instead use the String methods `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` which will test if the two Strings contain the same characters in the same order. So, for example do:

```
String command = e.getActionCommand();
if("Panel1".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    changePanel(panel1);
} else if("Panel2".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
    changePanel(panel2);
}
```

**Edit:** Better still, use a CardLayout to swap JComponents: [The CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and [the CardLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

**Edit 2:** Note that your use of `org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication` means that you are using the JSR 296: Swing Application Framework library, and a review of the status of this library shows that it has been withdrawn as noted [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=296). So it does not appear that this library is currently being supported or updated.

Comment: You're welcome. Again, seriously consider using the CardLayout as it can make your life much easier.

Comment: yes i have implemented cardlayout but can you help me in menu action event??

I want to add "Menu2" As menu(not as menu item) then what i need to do? Because I have done cardlayout but failed to implement for menu

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @user1536: consider asking a new question giving pertinent details and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.